# What do these puns mean?

Tags: pun

I have puns that I don't get it and actually need them for translating an essay. Can anyone help me, please?

> 1. “Have you heard about the guy whose whole left side was cut off? He’s all right now.”

and

> 2. “Did you hear about the par-a-dox? . . . Doctor Shapiro and Doctor Miller.”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1) **All right** (only has a right side) = **Alright** (not in any danger/fine).

2) **Par-a-dox** (paradox)  = **Pair of docs** (two doctors are being referred to).

Answer (score 2):

1) He's all right [okay] [only has a right side]

2) paradox [pair of docs/doctors]